# How to get the remoteUser for a request with express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using a basicAuth middleware in my app, and it works.

But then, in my routes functions, I would like to get the login that was used by the user to authenticate. Assuming req is my request variable, this was supposed to be in req.remoteUser (and later in req.user).

But currently both are set to 'true'. I check that the middleware is used before calling app.use(app.router), so the req request should be populated ! I also use a bodyParser on the line right after basicAuth, and it populates the request correctly.

Nothing much on google, only one issue in express github saying that now it works and both req.user and req.remoteUser have the value.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, this is a bug in the async version of the auth checking (the sync version works). See https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1782 for more details.

Comment: it's not a bug, [it's a feature](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1782#issuecomment-26525086) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to provide the username to the callback function (even if the calling code obviously has it in it's context) if we want req.user to be set.

So intead of doing this (as the great tutorial I followed said) :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Authenticator
app.use(express.basicAuth(function(user, pass, callback) {
 var result = (user === 'testUser' && pass === 'testPass');
 callback(null /* error */, result);
}));

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
 res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

One must change the function into :

```
app.use(express.basicAuth(function(user, pass, callback) {
  if (user === 'testUser' && pass === 'testPass') {
    callback(null /* error */, user);
  } else {
    callback(null, null);
  }
}));
```

And for those wondering, yes that means we can't have a user whose name is the empty String (else it will be interpreted as false by express), which seems a shame.